# Find plagiarism in bulk articles

Tags: string-comparison, bulk, article, plagiarism-detection

I have a 20,000 collection of master articles and I will get about 400,000 articles of one or two pages everyday. Now, I am trying to see if each one of this 400k articles are a copy or modified version of my collection of master articles (a threshold of above 60% plagiarism is fine with me)
What are the algorithms and technologies I should use to tackle the problem in a very efficient and timely manner. 
Thanks

Comment: Well [here's one relevant paper](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/publications/PAPERS/7444/TR-2004-164.pdf) not sure if it's useful to you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fingerprint the articles (i.e. intelligently hash them based on the word frequency) and then look for statistical connection between the fingerprints.  Then if there is a hunch on some of the data set, do a brute force search for matching strings on those.

Comment: Nice answer: +1, but typo on brute force, please fix it.

Comment: Which algorithm do you suggest for hashing?
What kind of statistical connection do you mean? 
is Cosine Similarity a good idea?

Comment: Well, one simple hash would be to sort the words in each document by length and then ignore all the common words (or most of them).  Then possibly figure out the word distance between some of the less common words.  This would give you a rough fingerprint/hash, (a list of properties).  Then you need a way to see if one hash is similar to another.  Take two hashes side by side.  Look at the number of large word distances that agree and give it some sort of weighting score and do this for each of the properties and add the score together.  ...  get the idea?